# how to get sure that weblogic am using is standard edition and not enterprise edition?

Tags: version, weblogic12c

Need to understand main difference in enterprise ,standard and express version of any software.

Log snippet from weblogic server

```
<Dec 29, 2017 1:35:06 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.>
<Dec 29, 2017 1:35:06 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <The server started in RUNNING mode.>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a separate download for Weblogic Standard or Enterprise. However when it comes to using or enabling features, you are not licensed to use Clustering nor Java Mission Control for the JVM. So provided you don't enable these features, you are using Weblogic Standard.

Comment: Thanks radimpe .How to enable these features?